# Magit: How turn SHA1's in commit messages into links?

Tags: magit

Is there a way in magit to turn SHA1 hashes in the commit-message body into a clickable link? (currently it's necessary to click on the SHA1 and press Enter).

Related to: [How to follow commit hashes in commit messages?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29907)